# Haskell bind operator in System F including kinds

Tags: haskell, lambda, system-f

I need to know what is the System F type of the Haskell bind type (>>=) operator.

Until now I writed it like this:

```
(M::*->* A::*) -> (A::* -> (M::*->* B::*)) -> (M::*->*  B:*)
```

Is it right? If it is right how do I find the final result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Add explicit quantifiers for type variables, and remove the type annotations on each variable use.

```
∀M:*->*. ∀A:*. ∀B:*. M A -> (A -> M B) -> M B
```

I used the more conventional `:` instead of Haskell's `::`.

Note however that System F has no higher kinds (e.g. `*->*`), so the type above can only be found in more powerful type systems (e.g. [System Fω](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F#System_F.CF.89)).

Further, above I "conveniently" omitted the typeclass restriction on `M`, which makes the type close to, but not-quite, the Haskell type of `>>=`. (Also see the comment below by @DanielWagner).

This swept-under-the-rug detail is important. Otherwise, the type above is so general that it is not inhabited -- no lambda term has that type. Indeed, assume by contradiction there is `f` having the general type above. Then,

```
f (λt:*. t->⊥) : ∀A,B:* . (A -> ⊥) -> (A -> B -> ⊥) -> B -> ⊥
```

where ⊥ is any empty type (e.g. `Void`, in Haskell). But then, taking `⊤` to be any nonempty type (e.g. `()`, in Haskell) with inhabitant `u`, we obtain

```
f (λt:*. t->⊥) ⊥ : ∀B:* . (⊥ -> ⊥) -> (⊥ -> B -> ⊥) -> B -> ⊥
f (λt:*. t->⊥) ⊥ ⊤ : (⊥ -> ⊥) -> (⊥ -> ⊤ -> ⊥) -> ⊤ -> ⊥
f (λt:*. t->⊥) ⊥ ⊤ (λx:⊥. x) : (⊥ -> ⊤ -> ⊥) -> ⊤ -> ⊥
f (λt:*. t->⊥) ⊥ ⊤ (λx:⊥. x) (λx:⊥. λy:⊤. x) : ⊤ -> ⊥
f (λt:*. t->⊥) ⊥ ⊤ (λx:⊥. x) (λx:⊥. λy:⊤. x) u : ⊥
```

so `⊥` is inhabited -- contradiction.

More informally, the above merely proves that `data T a = T (a -> Void)` can not be a monad.

Comment: I guess there's something odd about the typeclass constraint that exists in Haskell but not in this signature. You could imagine writing this signature for some concrete choice of `M`, or give a typeclass dictionary as a first argument (so that `(>>=)` is merely projecting out the appropriate field of a record) or something... Probably not worth changing the answer, but something to be aware of for people consuming the answer.

Comment: @DanielWagner That is indeed a very important point. I should at least mention it...